# Микроархитектура Mic-2

Tags: процессор, микроархитектура

В микропрограмме для микроархитектуры Mic-2 микрокоманда if_icmpeq6 выполняет переход к T, если бит Z установлен в 1. Однако микрокоманда T та же, что и для goto1. А можно ли перейти к goto1 сразу, и станет ли машина работать быстрее после этого?